# How can I limit the amount of data in my db2 warehouse on cloud entry instance?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have an entry plan instance of DB2 Warehouse on Cloud that I'm looking to use for development of a streaming application.

If I keep the data to <= 1GB, it will cost me $50/month.  I'm worried that I could easily fill the database up with 20GB and the cost jumps up to $1000/month.

Is there a way that I can limit the amount of data in my DB2 Warehouse on Cloud to < 1GB?

Answer (score 0):

As per this link
[Db2 Warehouse pricing plans](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dashdb)

You will not be charged anything as long as your data usage does not exceed 1 GB.  From 1 GB to 20 GB the price will vary based on the data used.

You should be able to see the current % of usage at any time in your console.  Other than that I am not aware of any method to automatically restrict the usage to less than 1 GB at this time.

One of the problem would be the data compression which determines the actual amount of data stored and it can vary based on the type of data stored.

Hope this helps.

Regards
Murali